# How can gnuplot check for valid values within a plot loop?

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot, nan

I want to calculate histograms from a file "a_test.dat" like this:

```
# block_1
x y
1 1979.2
1 1598.6
1 1430.8
1 1544.7
1 1953.3
1 1288.8
1 1741.3
1 1791.1


# block_2
x y
2 2027
2 1591.4
2 1401.6
2 1923.7
2 1677
2 1311.1
2 1689.3
2 2015.8
```

So I define x_min and x_max, the number of bins (n_bins) and calculate the width of a bin:

```
x_min = 1250
x_max = 2250
n_bins = 20
bin_width = 1.*(x_max - x_min)/n_bins
```

For the histogram I take an array that I initialize with zeros:

```
array histo[n_bins]
do for [i=1:n_bins] {
    histo[i] = 0
}
```

Values ​​cannot belong to two bins. So I take the interval including the left boundary and not including the right boundary like [a,b[ :

```
leftInclude(x) = ( _i=int( floor( column(x)/bin_width ) ), histo[_i] = histo[_i] + 1 )
```

The following command works as long as "column(x)/bin_width" is defined (not NaN). How can I check for invalid results from "column(x)/bin_width"?

```
data_file = "a_test.dat"
data_blocks = "block_1 block_2"

set table $Temp
    plot for [i=1:words(data_blocks)] data_file index word(data_blocks, i) using ( leftInclude("y") ) w table 
unset table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Actually, you want to create and plot a histogram, but you are doing it in an "unusual" way and hence running into problems.

Unless there is a reason that you *have to* use arrays, I would use the (what I would consider) the intended way in gnuplot using `smooth frequency` (check `help smooth`). There should be tons of examples out there.

If you nevertheless want to do it via arrays, I'm sure there is a way to do it using `valid()`, check `help valid`.

**Script:**

```
### create histograms (smooth frequency)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# block_1
x y
1 1979.2
1 1598.6
1 1430.8
1 1544.7
1 1953.3
1 1288.8
1 1741.3
1 1791.1


# block_2
x y
2 2027
2 1591.4
2 1401.6
2 1923.7
2 1677
2 1311.1
2 1689.3
2 2015.8
EOD

x_min = 1250
x_max = 2250
n_bins = 20
bin_width = 1.*(x_max - x_min)/n_bins

bin(col) = floor(column(col)/bin_width)*bin_width

set boxwidth bin_width
set style fill transparent solid 0.3
set xtics out
set key top left
set xrange[x_min-bin_width:x_max+bin_width]

data_blocks = "block_1 block_2"

set multiplot layout 2,1
    do for [i=1:words(data_blocks)] {
        plot $Data u (bin(2)):(1) index i-1 smooth freq \
            w boxes lc i ti word(data_blocks,i) noenhanced
    }
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]